# Using listview/datagrid in umbraco massively increases load time

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, viewstate, umbraco, page-load-time

I am using the listview control and i have like 4 list view controls in a user control. It works perfectly with VS2010 and loads the page in 4 secs but when I move the control to umbraco(create a macro) and build a page using it, umbraco nearly takes 1 min to load the page.

After digging, I found that it's the viewstate that's causing the prob.Hence if I disable the view state umbraco loads the page in 6sec that's really good but the problem is the form fields are not persisted which is obvious.

So is there a workaround to fix this? I wish to have the viewstate turned on(or by any means persist the data) and umbraco should be able to load the page in less than 5 secs.

Please help.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: From where you are taking the data to bind the listview? Is it a custom db or Umbarco db?

Comment: You can try paging in listview. Only load the data corresponding to that page.

Comment: Can you tell what is taking the time? Is it in the back-end processing or in the delivery to the page / rendering?

Comment: @mahesh: Thanks for it, but it doesn't fix the isuue. Its from custom DB. Please post if you hav any other alternative. Thanks

Comment: @benni_mac_b : Thanks benni but I am not sure what causes it. It causes issues only when the page is rendered from umbraco, so no clue why umbraco takes so long to render listviews.

Comment: @Aneesh : You can check whether this is an issue in rendering listview control only. Its better to place a simple macro in a template without any styles or anything. So it must be a template with this macro only. Then using custom paging also. Please try this and check render time..

Answer (score 0):

How big is the viewstate?

Do you realise the data is extracted from the viewstate at runtime by JS, which depending on the viewstate many not be quick.

viewstate and the whole .net postback model should be consigned to history...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do realize it's get rendered by JS, that's the reason I guess umbraco takes a while to render the page. So waht would be the possible work around for this.

Also how do I get the size of viewstate of the page. 

Thanks

Comment: Somethings like this - document.forms[0].__VIEWSTATE.value.length - in the console will give it to you